# access iCloud notes in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, icloud, icloud-api

Is it possible to access notes (from the ios/macOS Apps) which are stored in iCloud from a iOS and/or cocoa App?

Any examples or links to a documentation?
I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hi @mik, have you figured out how to do that?